# Disable both password manager and info header in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I want to user puppeteer to help auto login into my website and also I want to browser to be visible. In addition, I want to disable info header "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" and the pop up password manager saving password of chrome.

I can found answer for each part but there is no solution that work for both.

Setting

```
puppeteer.launch({args=['--password_manager_enabled=false']})
```

will help to disable pop up of password manager.

Setting

```
puppeteer.launch({
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']
})
```

will disable the message "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" but the password manager flag effect will get removed.

Is there a way to achieve both ?